# How to install Wildcard SSL Cert on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7, ssl, wildcard

I have a GoDaddy WildCard Certificate Installed in my Windows 2008 R2 Box.
I'm running IIS 7.5

My cert is for *.MyDomain.com

I plan to use it on 50-100 sub domains. Each one will have a unique IP.
I have the cert installed the on server.

for some reason it only works on the 1st site i installed, and not other sites.
Those other sites just point to the first site when accesses via https
- and yes, I just a different IP for those sites.

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That definitely sounds like a symptom of all the sites using the same IP address. If you are sure each site is bound to a different site, maybe try these instructions: http://microsync.net/web-server/run-iis-and-apache-webserver-on-same-machine-on-same-port-80.html

Since it is a wildcard certificate, you can also put all the sites on the same IP address and configure them to use the certificate using these instructions: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html

Comment: I found the error.
tips
1) install the firefox extension that show's you the ip address of a website in the status bar (it really helps)
2) in my domain registrar's dns congif, I forgot to add the records for the new domains